# each() and list() function

Tags: php, iterator

I don't understand the each() and the list() function that well. Can anyone please give me a little more detail and explain to me how can it be useful?

**Edit:**

```
<?php
$foo = array("bob", "fred", "jussi", "jouni", "egon", "marliese");
$bar = each($foo);
print_r($bar);
?>

Array
(
    [1] => bob
    [value] => bob
    [0] => 0
    [key] => 0
)
```

So does this mean in array[1] there's the value bob, but it's clearly in array[0]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list` is not a function per se, as it is used quite differently.

Say you have an array

```
$arr = array('Hello', 'World');
```

With `list`, you can quickly assign those different array members to variables

```
list($item1, $item2) = $arr; //$item1 equals 'Hello' and $item2 equals 'World'
```

Comment: @Doug — Functions which return multiple values, for one.  Say you have a function which, when passed a filename, will return both its extension and MIME type as a two-element array.  You could then capture both values as e.g. `list($ext, $mime) = getTypes($filename);`.

Comment: Simpler, less verbose array-value extraction into the local scope.

Note that, sadly, it only works on numerically indexed arrays.

Comment: @Doug: Very simple example: `list($firstname, $surname) = explode(' ', "Tim Cooper");` Generally, it helps when you have any sort of array, but want to assign its values to uniquely named variables. Why you might want to do *that* depends on the situation. :)

Comment: The `list()` function currently has a warning on it regarding the order of how it assigns values. In PHP 5 it assigned values starting with the right-most value. In PHP 7 in starts with the left-most value. For more information see the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Answer (score 5):

The each() function returns the current element key and value, and moves the internal pointer forward.
[each()](http://ch.php.net/each)

The list function  — Assigns variables as if they were an array
[list()](http://ch.php.net/list)

**Example usage is for iteration through arrays**

```
  while(list($key,$val) = each($array))
    {
      echo "The Key is:$key \n";
      echo "The Value is:$val \n";

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A very common example for `list` is when thinking about CSV files. Imagine you have a simple database stored as CSV with the columns `id`, `title` and `text`, such a file could look like this:

```
1|Foo|Lorem ipsum dolor|
2|Bar|sit amet|
...
```

Now when you parse this file you could do it like this, using the `list` function:

```
$lines = file( 'myFile.csv' );
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $lines ); $i++ )
{
    list( $id, $title, $text, $null ) = explode( '|', $lines[$i], 4 );
    echo "Id: $id, Title: $title\n$text\n\n";
}
```

The other function, `each`, is basically just an old way to walk through arrays, using internal pointers. A more common way to do that is by using `foreach` now.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: its probably worth noting that `each` has been deprecated

> Warning: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged

---

lets look first at `each()` : it returns the current value (at first that's `$array[0 | "first value in association array ]` . so

```
  $prices = ('x'=>100 , 'y'=>200 , 'z'= 300 );
```

say I wanna loop over these array without using a foreach loop .

```
while( $e = each($prices) ){
    echo $e[key] . "  " . $e[value] . "<br/>" ; 
}
```

when each reaches point at a non existing element that would cause 
the while loop to terminate . 
When you call `each()`, it gives you an array with four values and the four indices to the array locations.The locations 'key' and 0 contain the key of the current element, and the locations 'value' and 1 contain the
value of the current element.

so this loop would list each key of the array a space and the value then

secondly lets look at `list()` . 
it basically will do the same thing with renaming of 'value' and 'key' although it has to be use in conjunction with `each()`

```
while( list($k , $v ) = each($prices) ){
    echo $k /*$e[key]*/  . "  " . $v /*$e[value]*/ . "<br/>" ;
    }
```

So in a nutshell `each()` iterates over the array each time returning an array  . `list()` rename the value , key pairs of the array to be used inside the loop .

NOTICE : `reset($prices)` :

resets `each()` pointer for that array to be the first element .

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.php.net/list

list isn't a function, it is a language construct. It is used to assign multiple values to different variables.

`list($a, $b, $c) = array(1, 2, 3);`

Now `$a` is equal to `1`, and so on.

- http://www.php.net/each

Every array has an internal pointer that points to an element in its array. By default, it points to the beginning.

`each` returns the current key and value from the specified array, and then advances the pointer to the next value. So, put them together:

`list($key, $val) = each($array);`

The RHS is returning an array, which is assigned to `$key` and `$val`. The internal pointer in `$array' is moved to the next element.

Often you'll see that in a loop:

```
while(list($key, $val) = each($array)):
```

It's basically the same thing as:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val):
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your first edit:

Basically, PHP is creating a hybrid array with the key/value pair from the current element in the source array.

So, you can get the key by using `$bar[0]` and the value by using `$bar[1]`.  OR, you can get the key by using `$bar['key']` and the value using `$bar['value']`.  It's always a single key/value pair from the source array, it's just giving you two different avenues of accessing the actual key and actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a multi-dimensional array:

```
+---+------+-------+
|ID | Name | Job   |
| 1 | Al   | Cop   |
| 2 | Bob  | Cook  |
+---+------+-------+
```

You might do something like:

```
<?php
while(list($id,$name,$job) = each($array)) {
    echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=".$id."\">".$name."</a> is a ".$job;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using them together is, basically, an early way to iterate over associative arrays, especially if you didn't know the names of the array's keys.

Nowadays there's really no reason I know of not to just use `foreach` instead.

`list()` can be used separately from `each()` in order to assign an array's elements to more easily-readable variables.

Comment: What?  Except list doesn't work for associative keys, only numeric keys.

Comment: Right.  It has to be used in conjunction with each().  each() uses the array's internal pointer, pulls the current array element, and creates an array that has the key indexed to 0 and the value indexed to 1.